# RuntimeError : cannot open

Tags: arcpy, arcmap, arcgis-10.2, runtimeerror

I have the code below

```
import arcpy, os

from arcpy.sa import *


arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True

fc = r'E:\my saves\finaldata.dbf\finaldataD'
# Point feature class, needs to be in a file geodatabase (for the where clause to work)
output_folder = r'C:\GIS\data\testdata'  # Where the rasters will be saved

date_field = 'date'  # field holding the dates (date type, not string)
value_fields = ['CO', 'O3', 'NO2']  # field with the values to interpolate

all_dates = list({i[0] for i in arcpy.da.SearchCursor(fc, date_field)})  # List all unique dates

for date in all_dates:
    # Create a feature layer of each unique date
    where = "{0}=date '{1}'".format(arcpy.AddFieldDelimiters(datasource=fc, field=date_field),
                                    date.strftime('%Y-%m-%d'))
    arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(in_features=fc, out_layer='lyr', where_clause=where)

    # For each field interpolate. This is untested since I dont have spatial analyst
    for fieldname in value_fields:
        outIDW = Idw(in_point_features='lyr', z_field=fieldname,
                     cell_size=10)  # , {power}, {search_radius}, {in_barrier_polyline_features})
        outIDW.save(os.path.join(output_folder, '{0}_{1}.tif'.format(fieldname, date.strftime('%Y%m%d'))))
```

but in the result I got runtime error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/USER/AppData/Roaming/JetBrains/PyCharm2020.1/scratches/arcgis.py", line 15, in <module>
    all_dates = list({i[0] for i in arcpy.da.SearchCursor(fc, date_field)})  # List all unique dates
RuntimeError: cannot open 'E:\my saves\finaldata.dbf\finaldataD'
```

can anyone tell me how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Shouldnt:

`fc = r'E:\my saves\finaldata.dbf\finaldataD'`

be:

`fc = r'E:\my saves\finaldata.gdb\finaldataD'`